# FirebaseAnalytics setCurrentScreen W/FA: setCurrentScreen cannot be called while no activity active

Tags: android

**My code**

```
in onCreate ： mFirebaseAnalytics = FirebaseAnalytics.getInstance(this); 

onResume ： String screenName = "Main";

        // [START set_current_screen]
        mFirebaseAnalytics.setCurrentScreen(this, screenName, null /* class override */);
        // [END set_current_screen]
```

**But always**

W/FA: setCurrentScreen cannot be called while no activity active

I don't know why, I hope you can help me

Answer (score 0):

I guess it's too late.
But maybe use full dCalling it in onRsume

Comment: better edit your answer with code so easy to understand than the theory

Comment: // Variable decelaration private FirebaseAnalytics mFirebaseAnalytics;

// And in Oncreate initialize  FirebaseAnalytics variable 
mFirebaseAnalytics = FirebaseAnalytics.getInstance(this);

 // Than in onResume  add setCurrentScreen 
mFirebaseAnalytics.setMinimumSessionDuration(100L);
mFirebaseAnalytics.setCurrentScreen(SplashScreen.this, "Splash Page", "Splash");

Splash Page is “screenName”. Splash  is “screenClass”